# What is the most standard way to display 3d content in a browser?

Tags: javascript, web, web-standards

I want to replace a flash applet that displays a three dimensional matrix of dots (up to 200.000). I want the content to be displayed in the majority of web browsers, including mobile browers, by using standard web technology. I know that flash is very popular and almost multiplatform, but it is not a standard. Can this be achieved with standard web technology?

Comment: if its not complex, you can use CSS3, if its a full blown 3D scene, webGL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With web standards you have two possibilities: WebGL and CSS 3D Transforms

The [browser support for WebGL](http://caniuse.com/#search=webgl) isn't very good.
But with [3D transforms](http://caniuse.com/#search=3d%20transforms), you will miss a few browsers as well.

Which technology better suits your needs is hard to tell without knowing too much, from what I imagine WebGL would be more appropriate for you.

Either way, you probably will have to include the Flash Version as a Fallback for browsers who don't support WebGL/3D Transforms.

Comment: I have made some research and discovered that WebGL is not a W3C standard and only the cutting edge browsers supports it. And IE, iOS and android are still unsupported. Maybe it's not worth the effort :(

Comment: It's still an open standard, just maintained by the Khronos Group instead the W3C.

Answer (score 0):

The best standard that I've found thus far is [X3D](http://www.web3d.org/x3d/what-x3d). This standard does not have good browser support, but [X3DOM](http://www.x3dom.org) is a javascript implementation of X3D that does (it uses other browser technologies to implement X3D). You can find browser support information for X3DOM [here](http://www.x3dom.org/contact/).

For your dot matrix, the X3D [PointSet](http://doc.x3dom.org/author/Rendering/PointSet.html) node appears to do what you want.